# Add attribute to custom tab at product edit page in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9

I added a module for custom product relations with the following how to: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-product-relations-in-magento/. For that relations, a custom tab is added at the product edit page in the admin panel. Everything works fine, but now I would like to have a custom attribute, which is also generated via the installer script of the module, to that tab above the product relation grid. Is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please include relevant code here. if that link becomes a 404 this question will be meaningless for future users